# Using multiple ResponseObserver.onNext will stuck the service - gRPC Java

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java

I want to send data in chunks of 50 with gRPC, however when running `responseObserver.onNext` multiple times, it just get stuck and wont send the data. But when I stop the stream, I get the data.

This is my code:

```java
// List<List<MyClass>> listOfMyClass
for (List<MyClass> myClasses : listOfMyClass) {
  responseObserver.onNext(buildReply(myClasses));
}
responseObserver.onCompleted();
```

This will make it stuck. But, if I only run `responseObserver.onNext(buildReply(myClasses));` once, I will get the data instantly.

My proto:

```proto
message Request {
    string number = 1;
}

message Reply {
    repeated CustomMessage results = 1;
}

service Service {
    rpc MyRequest (Request) returns (stream Reply) {}
}
```

I've been using a GUI called https://github.com/uw-labs/bloomrpc, which should display the stream easily.

Answer (score 0):

The `StreamObserver` interface is non-blocking and doesn't provide back pressure for outbound data. In order to give the client the back pressure, you need to cast the `StreamObserver` that the client uses to send the data to ServerCallStreamObserver, and observe the "ready" bit. Something like this:

```java
ClientCallStreamObserver<MyClass> clientCallStreamResponseObserver =
      (ClientCallStreamObserver<File>) responseObserver;
clientCallStreamObserver.setOnReadyHandler(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      sendUntilNotReady(clientCallStreamResponseObserver);
    }
});
sendUntilNotReady(clientCallStreamResponseObserver);

...

private void sendUntilNotReady(ClientCallStreamObserver<MyClass> clientCallStreamResponseObserver) {
  while (clientCallStreamResponseObserver.isReady()) {
    clientCallStreamResponseObserver.onNext(... /* build reply for next item in listOfMyClass */);
  }
}
```